# RegEx: Extract substring from a string which may contain several number of '{' and '}'

Tags: javascript, regex, string, ckeditor

```
`<html>
<head>
  <title>DailyHoroscope.com</title>
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    {if $contact['timezone']} 
     {assign var=local_tz value=$contact['timezone']} 
    {else} 
     {assign var=local_tz value='America/New_York'} 
    {/if} 
    {assign var=tracking_params value="utm_medium={$medium}&utm_source={$source}&utm_campaign={$campaign}"}
</head>
<body style="background:#fff;">
</body>
</html>`
```

In this code I need to get substrings inside {}.
I am using this RegEx

```
/\{([^}]*)\}/mig
```

Its working fine in case of those types of substring which contains only one { and }. like

```
{if $contact['timezone']}
```

but incase of this string--->

```
{assign var=tracking_params value="utm_medium={$medium}&utm_source={$source}&utm_campaign={$campaign}"}
```

I am expecting the whole string as result, but its returning me

```
{assign var=tracking_params value="utm_medium={$medium},
{$source} and {$campaign}
```

and that is right because my regex is ending after getting the first '}' ; is there any way to get the string which will contain same number of '{' and '}' using regEx? What will be the RegEx ?

Comment: This is not a job to be done with regex, especially when JavaScript regex is not even equipped with enough feature to properly match nested `{}`. Even if it is, it is better to write a proper parser to take care of this.

Answer (score 1):

Provided you only have 1 level of nested curly braces, you can use

```
\{((?:[^{}]*\{[^{}]*\})*[^}]*)\}
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pE5dP4/2)

Matches:

```
if $contact['timezone']
assign var=local_tz value=$contact['timezone']
else
assign var=local_tz value='America/New_York'
/if
assign var=tracking_params value="utm_medium={$medium}&utm_source={$source}&utm_campaign={$campaign}"
```

Comment: The biggest problem here is that JS doesn't support balancing groups. So, we can only use regex workarounds like this, expanding the limit of nested levels..